# ImageView should have the same height as the layout on the right

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface, view

I would like the imageview to have the same height as the LinearLayout on the right.
I don't want to fix any height and I would like to keep the image aspect ratio.

[image: Layout]

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ati" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with the **Right layout**. And set its height `wrap_content`
2. Then have an `ImageView` with the following properties:

   a. `align top` to the **Right layout**

   b. `alight bottom` to the **Right layout**

   c. `layout_height = "wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

try using the layout params to create same height and bitmap for aspect ratio